# How to dynamic nav menu and how to call all class

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I register menu in functions. in Output i call wp_nav_menu with theme location, menu id, menu class but I could not call li and a class. How can I call li and a class

```
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ftco-nav" aria-controls="ftco-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="fa fa-bars"></span> Menu
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="services.html" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="project.html" class="nav-link">Project</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="blog.html" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add classes to your menu items, you can do this in your backend under Design -> Menus -> in the top right toggle "screen options" -> select "css classes". After that you can add classes to your menu items.

---

Maybe you want to change the complete output of your menu, you can use wp_get_nav_menu_items function. You give it the id (hover over the "delete menu" link and it shows you the id in the url) and you get the menu items:

```
<?php
    $menuID = '12'; // ID of your menu
    $primaryNav = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuID); // get your menu items
?>
```

Now you can all the items of your menu and can use a foreach and output all the items with your individual markup.

```
<ul id="ftco-nav">
    <?php
        foreach( $primaryNav as $item ) {
            $link = $item->url; // get the url of item
            $title = $item->title; // get title of item
            ?>

            <li class="item"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></li>

    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

You can give the ul and li all the classes you like to and still have all the items from your menu.

Maybe you want to give the "active" class, so the active menu item has a different styling, when the page is viewed. For this you can get the current url and check, if it is the same as the link of your menu item. If it is, you set the active class. So your code would look like this:

```
<ul id="ftco-nav">
    <?php
        foreach( $primaryNav as $item ) {
            $link = $item->url; // get the url of item
            $title = $item->title; // get title of item
            $active_page = false;
            $current_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
            if ($link == $current_url) { $active_page = true; }
        ?>

        <li class="item <?php if ($active_page == true) { echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></li>

    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

This way you can completely individualize your menu, without the need to use custom walker or filters. Hope this helps.